# Strings inside left drop down menu

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to modify strings inside an apk, I could find almost all strings at the strings.xml file, but there are still strings I can't find as shown in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfOlR.png)

I tried to use the Ctrl + Shift + F to search in the entire proyect but no results, I even tried to search for harcoded strings but same result, are they stored at somewhere else? are they added with java code inside files? does anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and restart once check it.